# How to set ringtone programmatically in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, ringtone

I want to set ringtone programmatically in Blackberry through my app, but I am not finding any sample code.

I tried this, but it's not working:

```
net.rim.device.api.notification.NotificationsManager.setPhoneRingTone("a1.mp3");
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you giving the Path correctly. Check once.

Comment: Is this ringtone a mp3 file that's a resource in your app?  Or a ringtone on the device?  Have you tried using the full path?  *(perhaps you're looking for something in /system/samples/ringtones/ or /home/user/ringtones)*.  Does `setPhoneRingTone()` throw an exception? (if so, which one)

Comment: @alishaik786 yes, I am giving the whole path correctly.

Comment: @Nate I have tried by three ways means saving on sd card and on device memory or as shown in my above code i had placed the a1.mp3 file in my project resource folder too. but there is no exception and no output too. and Ringtone is not setting.

Answer (score 1):

> You cannot directly access and play the RIM tones - they are
>   content-protected.   What you *can* do is set up your own alert
>   profile that is added to the BB Profiles. This profile can access the
>   on-board ringtones. You fire this profile using NotificationManager.
>   See the NotificationsDemo that ships wiht the JDE.

Source: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Ring-Tones/m-p/343755#M63152

Comment: I am not trying to play RIM Tones.I want to play my own tone which i am saving through my app on device or sd card.